# How to scraping modern sites or sites with loader css with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm still racking my brain on how to scrape these types of sites.

Right now I'm trying to get the HTML of a page that contains a loader and then displays the content of the site.

But when I want to scraping this data, it returns the html with the loader.

My python code:

```
from time import sleep
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

response = session.get('https://www.twitch.tv/')
response.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1, timeout=80)


with open('scraped.html', 'w+', encoding="utf-8") as filename:
    filename.write(response.text)
    filename.close()
```

And I getting this in my file response.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="tw-root--hover">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Twitch</title>
    <meta name="twitter:description"
        content="Twitch is an interactive livestreaming service for content spanning gaming, entertainment, sports, music, and more. Thereâs something for everyone on Twitch." />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="161273083968709" />
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Twitch" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Twitch" />
    <meta name="title" content="Twitch" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-static-metadata/twitch_logo3.jpg" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="Twitch" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Twitch" />
    <meta content="https://www.twitch.tv" property="og:url" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="id460177396" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="twitch.tv" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.twitch.tv" />
    <meta name="description"
        content="Twitch is an interactive livestreaming service for content spanning gaming, entertainment, sports, music, and more. Thereâs something for everyone on Twitch." />
    <meta content="tv.twitch.android.app" property="al:android:package" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="tv.twitch.android.app" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-static-metadata/twitch_logo3.jpg" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="twitch.tv" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="id460177396" />
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="Twitch is an interactive livestreaming service for content spanning gaming, entertainment, sports, music, and more. Thereâs something for everyone on Twitch." />
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="twitch.tv" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="twitch.tv" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Twitch" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitch" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="id460177396" />
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="Twitch" />
    <link media="only screen and(max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.twitch.tv" rel="alternate" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Twitch" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Twitch" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="bg" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=bg" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="cs" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=cs" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="da" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=da" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=de" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="el" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=el" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=es" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-mx" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=es-mx" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fi" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=fi" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=fr" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="hu" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=hu" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=it" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=ja" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=ko" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=nl" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="no" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=no" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=pl" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=pt" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt-br" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=pt-br" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ro" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=ro" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=ru" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sk" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=sk" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="sv" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=sv" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=th" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=tr" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="vi" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=vi" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-cn" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=zh-cn" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-tw" href="https://www.twitch.tv/?lang=zh-tw" />
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.twitch.tv" />
    <script
        type="application/ld+json">[{"@id":"https://www.twitch.tv/","@type":"Organization","name":"Twitch","sameAs":["https://www.facebook.com/Twitch/","https://www.linkedin.com/company/twitch-tv/","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitch.tv","https://twitter.com/twitch"],"url":"https://www.twitch.tv/"}]</script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32"
        href="https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/favicon-32-e29e246c157142c94346.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16"
        href="https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/favicon-16-52e571ffea063af7a7f4.png">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://api.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://passport.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://api.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/">
    <script>!function () { var e, t, n, i, r = { passive: !0, capture: !0 }, a = new Date, o = function () { i = [], t = -1, e = null, f(addEventListener) }, c = function (i, r) { e || (e = r, t = i, n = new Date, f(removeEventListener), u()) }, u = function () { if (t >= 0 && t < n - a) { var r = { entryType: "first-input", name: e.type, target: e.target, cancelable: e.cancelable, startTime: e.timeStamp, processingStart: e.timeStamp + t }; i.forEach((function (e) { e(r) })), i = [] } }, s = function (e) { if (e.cancelable) { var t = (e.timeStamp > 1e12 ? new Date : performance.now()) - e.timeStamp; "pointerdown" == e.type ? function (e, t) { var n = function () { c(e, t), a() }, i = function () { a() }, a = function () { removeEventListener("pointerup", n, r), removeEventListener("pointercancel", i, r) }; addEventListener("pointerup", n, r), addEventListener("pointercancel", i, r) }(t, e) : c(t, e) } }, f = function (e) { ["mousedown", "keydown", "touchstart", "pointerdown"].forEach((function (t) { return e(t, s, r) })) }, p = "hidden" === document.visibilityState ? 0 : 1 / 0; addEventListener("visibilitychange", (function e(t) { "hidden" === document.visibilityState && (p = t.timeStamp, removeEventListener("visibilitychange", e, !0)) }), !0), o(), self.webVitals = { firstInputPolyfill: function (e) { i.push(e), u() }, resetFirstInputPolyfill: o, get firstHiddenTime() { return p } } }()</script>
    <!-- WebTransport for https://www.twitch.tv -->
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial"
        content="Al4GgLnwUTx/Mj0WaK4mK57NRcL9E17I2UF7y650onwBWtPuXM4hlUhhoB/P3cc2WCrHFsARHeRUw5adb9KfCQ4AAABieyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL3R3aXRjaC50djo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiV2ViVHJhbnNwb3J0IiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjQzNzU5OTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZX0=">
    <!-- MSE in Workers for https://twitch.tv -->
    <meta http-equiv="origin-trial"
        content="Ag8gjMC7YpL/OUcwEHEkvOQaTSL//OWmEo9qcm/0rXZjbHCcN4YmRh7aBjNBOmmLwO3JqWrSUL6Qg1+eTmmXxAQAAABqeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL3R3aXRjaC50djo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiTWVkaWFTb3VyY2VJbldvcmtlcnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NDc5OTM1OTksImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlfQ==">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://gql.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cvp.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://pubsub-edge.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://static.twitchcdn.net/">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://gql.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://static.twitchcdn.net/">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://cvp.twitch.tv/">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/opensearch.xml">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root" class="root">
        <style>
            html {
                font-size: 62.5%
            }

            body {
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                background-color: #fafafa
            }

            .root,
            body,
            html {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
                position: relative
            }

            body.dark-theme {
                background-color: #000
            }

            .shell-nav {
                background: #fff;
                height: 5rem;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: stretch;
                -ms-flex-align: stretch;
                align-items: stretch
            }

            body.dark-theme .shell-nav {
                background: #18181b
            }

            html.desktop-login .shell-nav {
                display: none
            }

            .shell-nav__logo {
                padding-top: 1.3rem;
                padding-left: 1.3rem;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 0
            }

            .shell-nav__logo svg {
                fill: #9147ff
            }

            body.dark-theme .shell-nav__logo svg {
                fill: #9147ff
            }

            .shell-nav__link {
                padding: 2rem;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center
            }

            .shell-nav__link-list {
                display: flex
            }

            .shell-nav__link::after {
                content: '';
                height: .4rem;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
                border-radius: 2px
            }

            body.dark-theme .shell-nav__link::after {
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
            }

            .shell-nav__link--discovery::after {
                width: 6.9rem
            }

            .shell-nav__link--browse::after {
                width: 5.9rem
            }

            .shell-nav__link--follow::after {
                width: 7.6rem
            }

            .shell-nav__link--follow {
                display: none
            }

            body.logged-in .shell-nav__link--follow {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex
            }

            .shell-nav__ellipsis {
                width: 5rem;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                display: none;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center
            }

            .shell__svg--navmore {
                fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
                height: 2rem
            }

            .shell-nav__search-container {
                -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                -ms-flex-positive: 1;
                flex-grow: 1;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center
            }

            .shell-nav__search {
                display: none;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 40rem;
                height: 3rem;
                margin: 0 1rem;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
                border-radius: 2px
            }

            .shell-nav__user-card {
                width: 5rem;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: flex-end;
                box-sizing: border-box
            }

            .shell-nav__user-card-avatar {
                margin-right: 1rem;
                width: 3rem;
                height: 3rem;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
                -ms-flex-negative: 0;
                flex-shrink: 0;
                border-radius: 50%
            }

            body.dark-theme .shell-nav__user-card-avatar {
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .05)
            }

            .shell-nav__user-auth {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center
            }

            body.logged-in .shell-nav__user-auth {
                display: none
            }

            .shell-nav__user-auth-button {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
                height: 3rem;
                margin-right: 1rem;
                padding: .8rem;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-radius: 2px
            }

            .shell-nav__user-auth-button--login {
                width: 5.2rem
            }

            .shell-nav__user-auth-button--singup {
                width: 6.1rem
            }

            .shell-nav__user-auth-button::after {
                content: '';
                width: 100%;
                height: .4rem;
                border-radius: 3px;
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
                display: block
            }

            .shell-loader {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                opacity: 0;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                padding-top: 5rem;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-animation: shell-display .1s linear;
                animation: shell-display .1s linear;
                -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
                animation-delay: .3s;
                -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                overflow: hidden
            }

            html.desktop-login .shell-loader {
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 1rem
            }

            .shell-loader__spinner {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 2.2rem;
                height: 2.2rem;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
                border-top: 2px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .3);
                border-right: 2px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .3);
                border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .3);
                border-left: 2px solid #19171c;
                -webkit-animation: shell-loading-spinner 1s infinite linear;
                animation: shell-loading-spinner 1s infinite linear;
                border-radius: 50%;
                box-sizing: border-box
            }

            body.dark-theme .shell-loader__spinner {
                border-left: 2px solid #d9d8dd
            }

            @media screen and (max-width:1023px) {
                .shell-nav__search {
                    display: none
                }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width:767px) {
                .shell-nav__link-list {
                    display: none
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes shell-loading-spinner {
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    transform: rotate(360deg)
                }
            }

            @keyframes shell-loading-spinner {
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    transform: rotate(360deg)
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes shell-display {
                0% {
                    opacity: 0
                }

                100% {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            }

            @keyframes shell-display {
                0% {
                    opacity: 0
                }

                100% {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            }
        </style>
        <script>function prefersDarkMode() { var e = window.CSS && window.CSS.supports.bind(window.CSS) || window.supportsCSS; return !!(!!e && (e("--f:0") || e("--f", 0))) && (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) } -1 !== document.cookie.indexOf("twilight-user") || -1 !== document.cookie.indexOf("twilight-auth") ? document.querySelector("body").classList.add("logged-in") : window.__twitchIntegrations && window.__twitchIntegrations.app && document.querySelector("html").classList.add("desktop-login"), ("1" === localStorage.getItem("twilight.theme") || prefersDarkMode()) && document.querySelector("body").classList.add("dark-theme")</script>
        <div class="shell-nav">
            <figure class="shell-nav__logo"><svg width="40px" height="40px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 40 40" x="0px"
                    y="0px">
                    <g fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <path
                            d="M19 6v6h-2V6h2zm-7 0h2v6h-2V6zM5 0L0 5v18h6v5l5-5h4l9-9V0H5zm17 13l-4 4h-4l-4 4v-4H6V2h16v11z">
                        </path>
                        <path d="M18 17l4-4V2H6v15h4v4l4-4h4zM12 6h2v6h-2V6zm7 0h-2v6h2V6z" fill="#FFF"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg></figure>
            <div class="shell-nav__link-list">
                <div class="shell-nav__link shell-nav__link--discovery"></div>
                <div class="shell-nav__link shell-nav__link--follow"></div>
                <div class="shell-nav__link shell-nav__link--browse"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="shell-nav__ellipsis">
                <figure class="shell__svg--navmore"><svg width="20px" height="20px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        x="0px" y="0px">
                        <path
                            d="M4 8a2 2 0 1 1 0 4 2 2 0 0 1 0-4zm6 0a2 2 0 1 1 0 4 2 2 0 0 1 0-4zm6 0a2 2 0 1 1 0 4 2 2 0 0 1 0-4z"
                            fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </svg></figure>
            </div>
            <div class="shell-nav__search-container">
                <div class="shell-nav__search"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="shell-nav__user-auth">
                <div class="shell-nav__user-auth-button shell-nav__user-auth-button--login"></div>
                <div class="shell-nav__user-auth-button shell-nav__user-auth-button--singup"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="shell-nav__user-card">
                <div class="shell-nav__user-card-avatar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shell-loader" data-a-target="shell-loader">
            <div class="shell-loader__spinner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>window.__twilightApproximatedFirstPaint = performance.now()</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to get the real page, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you confirm the url?

Comment: Yes, the URL is https://www.twitch.tv/

Comment: maybe it needs to sleep much longer because JavaScript may need time to render content. Eventually you may use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (instead of requests_html)` without option `headless` to see browser window and see what page is doing.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the problem. I was missing 1 line of code so simple after passing the html.render, I had to use html.find(my_selector) with that I already got what I wanted. I don't use selenium because when uploading the API to the server it gives some problems.